# VS2015 complains about different SDK in global.json when running fromVS2015

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a project with a reference by src to another project.

When running from the command prompt with dnx web is works fine.

But running with CTRL-F5 (web) give me an error

> The context of the project at could not be determined. This can happen if a project references other projects by source, and those projects have a global.json file specifying a different version of the SDK.`

running with dnx-watch I got this error

> System.ArgumentException: The directory name C:\git\Localization\src\JsonLocalization\project.json is invalid.`

Main solution global.json

```js
{
  "projects": [
    "src",
    "test",
    "../TagHelpers/src",
    "../Mvc.JQuery.Datatables/src",
    "wrap",
    "../Localization/src"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta8"
  }
}
```

Main Project.json

```js
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-GGZDBC5-d96c66a6-1a4e-4a9a-b8d4-11c2f88ff638",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "CsvHelper": "2.13.1",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Http": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.SecretManager": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta8",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1-*",
        "Mvc6.JQuery.Datatables": "1.0.0-*",
        "npm": "1.4.15.2",
        "TagHelpers": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Localization": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "JsonLocalization": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "dependencies": {
                "DataTables": "1.0.0-*"
            },
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        }
    },
...
}
```

Localization
global.json

```js
{
    "projects": [
        "src",
        "test"
    ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta8"
    }
}`
```

project.json

```js
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Framework.Localization": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1-*"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this file exist C:\git\Localization\src\JsonLocalization\project.json ?

Comment: Can you also give more details about how/what you run? What command, what dnx is active when you run the watcher, etc? Btw, the sdk version in global.json is only used by VS so when you run from command line you might get a different version

Comment: thx. I tried a lot of thinks and it is now working again. Changing global.json by adding / removing the src reference didn't work any more. But adding this as an existing project in vs2015 did work. Now I can't remove it anymore. ( I remove it from global.json and .sln and project.json, close the solution, open the solution and the project is automatic restored??? (-;)

Answer (score 1):

### Restart Visual Studio!!!

After spending HOURS messing with this and getting errors like :

> RRStore.EF could not be determined. This can happen if a project
> references other projects by source, and those projects have a
> global.json file specifying a different version of the SDK.

I added a `global.json` file (which was otherwise nowhere to be seen) but that made no difference.

Then I eventually decided to try
Restart Visual Studio and it worked instantly even with no `global.json`

Answer (score 0):

I added the global.json at the wrong location. After moving the file to C:\git\Localization\global.json the project works fine under VS2015.

It seems that VS2015 doesn't add the project as there are reference conflict.
Adding as existing project to a solution will always work but lead sometimes to conflicts.

Removing the projects can be done with the folling steps.
* Remove from global.json.
* remove projects from solution (probably not needed any more)
* remove projects.json.lock

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning, this can occur if there are multiple `global.json` files.

In my case, I was referencing a dependency as a Git Submodule. I added the submodule projects to the primary solution in order to debug the dependency which caused the error listed in the OP.

Deleting the `global.json` (temporarily) from the submodule resolved the issue.